# How to limit scope of `using` statement outside of function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces, template-specialization

I want to define some static members of template specialization, like this:

```
namespace A {

template <> int C<A1::A2::...::MyClass1>::member1_ = 5;
template <> int C<A1::A2::...::MyClass1>::member2_ = 5;
template <> int C<A1::A2::...::MyClass1>::member3_ = 5;

template <> int C<B1::B2::...::MyClass2>::member1_ = 6;
template <> int C<B1::B2::...::MyClass2>::member2_ = 6;
template <> int C<B1::B2::...::MyClass2>::member3_ = 6;

...

}
```

But to simplify the code (and make it look more structured), I want to do something like this:

```
namespace A {

{
  using T = A1::A2::...::MyClass1;
  template <> int C<T>::member1_ = 5;
  template <> int C<T>::member2_ = 5;
  template <> int C<T>::member3_ = 5;
}

{
  using T = B1::B2::...::MyClass2;
  template <> int C<T>::member1_ = 6;
  template <> int C<T>::member2_ = 6;
  template <> int C<T>::member3_ = 6;
}

...

}
```

The compiler gives an error: `expected unqualified-id`. Are there ways to limit the `using` scope in an "outer" space?

Comment: did you compile in C++11 mode?

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, I do.

Comment: I undeleted my earlier answer of today with a new approach using namespace aliases.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot nest code blocks (i.e. `{...}`) outside functions.

Let's say we have this part in common:

```
namespace A1 { namespace A2 {
  class MyClass1;
}}

namespace B1 { namespace B2 {
  class MyClass2;
}}

namespace A {
template<typename T>
struct C
{
  static int member1_;
  static int member2_;
  static int member3_;
};
}
```

You can either [import the names into `namespace A`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b963d9c8f1ee0ec9), making them available through the qualification `A::`:

```
namespace A {
using A1::A2::MyClass1;
template <> int C<MyClass1>::member1_ = 5;
template <> int C<MyClass1>::member2_ = 5;
template <> int C<MyClass1>::member3_ = 5;

using B1::B2::MyClass2;
template <> int C<MyClass2>::member1_ = 6;
template <> int C<MyClass2>::member2_ = 6;
template <> int C<MyClass2>::member3_ = 6;
}
```

but I assume that is unwanted and you see this as pollution. So then the only thing you can do is [use an extra namespace](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9b414cfa694fa9f) to decrease the number of `::`:

```
namespace A {
namespace T {
using T1 = A1::A2::MyClass1;
using T2 = B1::B2::MyClass2;
}

template <> int C<T::T1>::member1_ = 5;
template <> int C<T::T1>::member2_ = 5;
template <> int C<T::T1>::member3_ = 5;


template <> int C<T::T2>::member1_ = 6;
template <> int C<T::T2>::member2_ = 6;
template <> int C<T::T2>::member3_ = 6;
}
```

This keeps your `namespace A` clear of unwanted typenames, although it introduces an "implementation namespace" `T` (which is a terrible name for a namespace!!!).

A third alternative [specializes `struct` template `C` for the types you want](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e37ff52ab68f78f0):

```
namespace A{
template<>
struct C<A1::A2::MyClass1>
{
  static const int member1_ = 5;
  static const int member2_ = 5;
  static const int member3_ = 5;
};

template<>
struct C<B1::B2::MyClass2>
{
  static const int member1_ = 5;
  static const int member2_ = 5;
  static const int member3_ = 5;
};
}
```

Note that this requires `static const` data members. You can also do away with a declaration of the `struct` template like so:

```
namespace A {
template<typename T>
struct C;
}
```

to limit its use (at compile time) to only the types you want. This would me my preferred solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult problem to solve. There are several constraints.

- template specializations have to happen at namespace scope, this rules out your local scope braces `{ }`.
- a template specialization lives in the same namespace as the primary template, this rules out local `namespace detail1 { }` and `namespace detail2 { }` inside `namespace A`. Although g++ incorrectly accepts this solution, but Clang correctly rejects this (Note: this was where I was stuck earlier today and temporarily deleted this answer).
- `using` directives and declarations pollute the namespace of all clients who include this header
- templates living in `inline` namespaces can be specialized inside all their enclosing namespace but declaring `namespace A` to be `inline` only works if it is enclosed by both the `A` and `B` namespace sequences, which is impossible.

The cleanest approach is to use [**namespace aliases**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1211399/819272) `libA` and `libB` for the lengthy `A1::A2::...::AN` and `B1::B2::...::BN` sequences of nested namespaces, and to export those aliases from their headers. This simplifies both client code and the actual template specializations.

```
#include <iostream>

// file C.h

namespace A {

template<class T> 
struct C 
{ 
    static int member1_, member2_, member3_; 
};

}   // namespace A

// file A.h

namespace A1 { namespace A2 {

struct MyClass1 {};

}} // namespace A1, A2

// export namespace alias to hide implementation details
namespace libA = A1::A2;    

namespace A {

template <> int C<libA::MyClass1>::member1_ = 5;
template <> int C<libA::MyClass1>::member2_ = 5;
template <> int C<libA::MyClass1>::member3_ = 5;

}   // namespace A

// file B.h 

namespace B1 { namespace B2 {

struct MyClass2 {};

}} // namespace B1, B2

// export namespace alias to hide implementation details
namespace libB = B1::B2;    

namespace A {

template <> int C<libB::MyClass2>::member1_ = 6;
template <> int C<libB::MyClass2>::member2_ = 6;
template <> int C<libB::MyClass2>::member3_ = 6;

}   // namespace A

// file main.cpp

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::C<libA::MyClass1>::member1_ << "\n";
    std::cout << A::C<libA::MyClass1>::member2_ << "\n";
    std::cout << A::C<libA::MyClass1>::member3_ << "\n";
    std::cout << A::C<libB::MyClass2>::member1_ << "\n";
    std::cout << A::C<libB::MyClass2>::member2_ << "\n";
    std::cout << A::C<libB::MyClass2>::member3_ << "\n";    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cccddaf51e90489).

Note that there is still a mild sympton of boiler plate in the repetition of the `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`, but the code is much more compact with the namespace aliases in place.