# how to use boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_vector_range with boost::numeric::ublas::basic_range<int> correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, ublas

I construct `boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<std::complex<double>,boost::numeric::ublas::row_major,0,boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<std::size_t>>` and then extract the diagonal part via `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_vector_range`. The source is:

```
#include<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>
#include<boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main()
{
   namespace ublas=boost::numeric::ublas;
   ublas::compressed_matrix<std::complex<double>,ublas::row_major,0,ublas::unbounded_array<std::size_t>>matrix(3,3);
   matrix.push_back(0,0,{1,1});
   matrix.push_back(0,1,{2,1});
   matrix.push_back(1,1,{3,1});
   matrix.push_back(2,2,{4,1});
   std::cout<<ublas::matrix_vector_range<decltype(matrix)>(matrix,ublas::basic_range<std::size_t>(0,matrix.size1()),ublas::basic_range<std::size_t>(0,matrix.size2()))<<std::endl;
}
```

and it works fine.

And then, because I need to pass the `compressed_matrix` to some FORTRAN function as well as the FORTRAN function requires the row and column indexes must be `int`, I change `std::size_t` to `int`. The new source code is:

```
#include<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>
#include<boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace ublas=boost::numeric::ublas;
  ublas::compressed_matrix<std::complex<double>,ublas::row_major,0,ublas::unbounded_array<int>>matrix(3,3);
  matrix.push_back(0,0,{1,1});
  matrix.push_back(0,1,{2,1});
  matrix.push_back(1,1,{3,1});
  matrix.push_back(2,2,{4,1});
  std::cout<<ublas::matrix_vector_range<decltype(matrix)>(matrix,ublas::basic_range<int>(0,matrix.size1()),ublas::basic_range<int>(0,matrix.size2()))<<std::endl;
}
```

After that I use `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -march=native -DNEBUG` to compile the source code and run the executable file (gcc version 4.9.1). The following error appears:

```
Check failed in file /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp at line 892:
start_ <= stop
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::ublas::bad_index'
  what(): bad index
Aborted
```

Then I go to */usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp* at line 892 and see:

```
BOOST_UBLAS_INLINE
    basic_range ():
        start_ (0), size_ (0) {}
    BOOST_UBLAS_INLINE
    basic_range (size_type start, size_type stop):
        start_ (start), size_ (stop - start) {
        BOOST_UBLAS_CHECK (start_ <= stop, bad_index ());
    }
```

But in my case `start_` is less than `stop`. So I have no idea why such error will appear. Any ideas what's causing it?

Comment: Consider using a [namespace alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211399/in-c-what-is-a-namespace-alias), it'll greatly improve readability. (The answer to the linked question uses `boost::numeric::ublas` as an example :))

Comment: What is `push_back`?  I thought the elements should be accessed as `matrix(i, j) = ...`

Comment: push_back() is from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/html/classboost_1_1numeric_1_1ublas_1_1compressed__matrix.html