# How to import multiple members of same namespace in single line using C++?

Tags: c++

I am a python programmer, and just learning some C++ on the side.

From what I understand, in C++  `using namespace std`
would be equivalent to python's `from std import *`, and should not be used.

*1)  Correct?*

And then in Python, I could do for example `from std import cout, cin`.

2)  Is there a single line equivalence?  Or would I have to do it in multiple lines?

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

Comment: To answer your first question: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf:  Thanks.  Though I am aware of the bad practice from python.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to simply use `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Comment: If you preface everything you can get burned if two different namespaces use the same name.  You can also use a [namespace alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211399/in-c-what-is-a-namespace-alias) to shorten long namespace names.

Comment: Since statements in C++ end with a ";", you can put multiple statements on the same line.

Though I don't guarantee that this would be any more readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly:

1. Correct.
2. There is no any single line equivalent for this.

Comment: how about using `std::cout; using std::cin;` it's a single line, but not a single statement.

Comment: @Alex It is not an single line equivalent but a single line form of writing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , there is one way you can import multiple members but its not supported everywhere.

```
using std::cout,std::endl;
```

But you will get a warning.

> warning:
>    comma-separated list in using-declaration only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z using std::cout,std::endl;                ^