# Can I use some but not all names from a namespace without having to repeat the full scope for all of them?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Several times in my code I write something like

```cpp
// all these using
using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::var1;
using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::var2;
using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::var3;
using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::fun1;
using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::fun2;
// to make this line cleaner
fun1(var1,fun2(var2,var3));
```

because I don't want to make any name from that namespace available, other then the 5 names I've listed.

Does C++ offer anything to use all those names without having to write the common part of the scope over and over?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++, what is a "namespace alias"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211399/in-c-what-is-a-namespace-alias)

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is a duplicate. This isn't about shortening the namespace, it's asking about a facility for reducing the number of `using` declarations in the same way that python has a `from package import x, y, z`. C++ has no such facility, but this doesn't really make the question a duplicate of "What is a namespace alias"

Comment: I saw some macro-fu using a sophisticated macro function that would allow you to do `USING(this::is::a::very::long::name::space, var1, var2, var3, fun1, fun2)` ... but I thought the "cure" was worse than the problem it was trying to solve (because I hate macros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`namespace` alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias):

```cpp
// Create an alias namespace of the long namespace
namespace shorter = this::is::a::very::long::name::space;

using shorter::var1;
using shorter::var2;
using shorter::var3;
using shorter::fun1;
using shorter::fun2;
```

If you make the alias short enough, you may not even need the `using` declarations at all. But otherwise there isn't any other convenient way to pull in a small amount of symbols from a namespace without pulling in everything.

C++ lacks any way to make symbols `x`,`y`,`z` visible from some namespace `ns` without requiring the repeated `using` declarations.

Comment: Mmm, this seems a _nice to have_ feature. Do you know if they are considering it in some way?

Comment: I agree that this would be a nice to have feature. I took a quick look through some of the recent/open proposals [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/), but I did not see anything explicitly for it (though I may have missed it). I would be surprised if it hasn't at least been proposed once.

Answer (score 3):

A key point in your question seems to be that you need to do it often. To alleviate that, you can prime those symbols in a designated namespace.

```
namespace common_stuff {
  // You can also use an alias as the other answer suggests to shorten this
  using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::var1;
  using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::var2;
  using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::var3;
  using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::fun1;
  using this::is::a::very::long::name::space::fun2;
}
```

A using declaration is a declaration, and so we created a namespace that contains *only* five declaration for the things you want. Now, in every scope you want those five to be visible for unqualified name lookup, you can simply add

```
using namespace common_stuff;
```

And only those five symbols from `common_stuff` will be made visible.