# Redirect all uses of an aliased namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, alias

I'm using a certain FooInstrumentsLib to control instruments, but in simulation mode I would like to redirect all instrument usage from e.g. `FooInstr1::Measure()` to `Sim::FooInstr1::Measure()`.

All my cpp files have `#include "stdafx.h"`, which has `#include "FooInstrumentsLib.h"` (the intended way of including the library) which, after another include, has `namespace { namespace FooInstr1 = someothernamespace; }`.

Ideally I'd be able to just redefine it, `#ifdef SIMULATION_MODE namespace FooInstr1 = Sim::FooInstr1`, but this won't compile because it makes `FooInstr1` an ambiguous symbol.

How can I best resolve this? Note that I still need some stuff from `FooInstrumentsLib.h`. I wouldn't want to rely on any implementation details of `FooInstrumentsLib` - better in that case to just change each instrument call to something aliasable, but I'm hoping not to have to do that.

Comment: ```#ifdef SIMULATION_MODE namespace FooInstr1 = Real::FooInstr1;#else namespace FooInstr1 = Sim::FooInstr1" ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias

Comment: I think the more regular approach is to inject a (simulator) class that implements the same interface as the production code. E.g. use dependency injection and unit tests to test your code first. So start by making an abstract baseclass for your instrument

Comment: See [What is namespace alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211399/what-is-a-namespace-alias)